# worker's first and last checks for each day

Tags: t-sql, timetable

I need the list of the each worker's first check-in and last check-out for each day...

What i get as a result from below query is, only one data for each day ...

```
SELECT 
    p.prsnCode [Sicil No]
    ,p.[prsnName1]
    ,p.[prsnName2]
    ,t.[ioTransactionDate]

      ,[Giris/Cikis] = (
  case 
  when [ioStatus] = 0 then 'Giris' 
  when [ioStatus] = 1 then 'Cikis' 
  else 'Uzaya Gitti' end )


  FROM [IOTransaction] t

  left join dbo.Person p on t.ioPrsnRefId = p.prsnRefId 

  where t.[ioTransactionDate] = (select MIN(m.[ioTransactionDate]) from IOTransaction m 
                                    where m.ioPrsnRefId = t.ioPrsnRefId and CAST(m.[ioTransactionDate] AS DATE) = CAST(t.[ioTransactionDate] AS DATE)
                                            group by m.ioPrsnRefId)
         OR t.[ioTransactionDate] = (select MAX(m.[ioTransactionDate]) from IOTransaction m 
                                    where m.ioPrsnRefId = t.ioPrsnRefId and CAST(m.[ioTransactionDate] AS DATE) = CAST(t.[ioTransactionDate] AS DATE)
                                            group by m.ioPrsnRefId)

group by t.ioPrsnRefId, prsnCode, prsnName1 , prsnName2, t.[ioTransactionDate], ioStatus 


    ORDER BY P.prsnCode
```

i also tried to add this `group by m.ioPrsnRefId, CAST(m.[ioTransactionDate] AS DATE)` to the where clause but it gives error... (Subquery returned more than 1 value.)

Comment: i cannot edit the question, the query seems working fine but it works about 3 minutes to list.

new question is , is there any way to fasten this query ?

Comment: Why don't you put your `Min(t.[ioTransactionDate]` and `Max(t.[ioTransactionDate])` in your select statement and then either remove the where clause or put in a date range for the `TransactionDate`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I've included the sample table and data I used in case I have made some incorrect assumptions.

```
create table person 
(
    prsnRefId int,
    prsnCode varchar(50),
    prsnName1 varchar(50),
    prsnName2 varchar(50)
);

create table IOTransaction
(
    ioPrsnRefId int,
    ioTransactionDate datetime,
    ioStatus int
);

insert into person values(1,'code1','Bob','Carolgees');
insert into person values(2,'code2','Diana','Dors');

insert into IOTransaction values(1,'01-jan-2016 09:00:00',0);
insert into IOTransaction values(1,'01-jan-2016 12:00:00',1);
insert into IOTransaction values(1,'01-jan-2016 13:00:00',0);
insert into IOTransaction values(1,'01-jan-2016 18:00:00',1);
insert into IOTransaction values(1,'02-jan-2016 09:01:00',0);
insert into IOTransaction values(1,'02-jan-2016 12:01:00',1);
insert into IOTransaction values(1,'02-jan-2016 13:01:00',0);
insert into IOTransaction values(1,'02-jan-2016 18:01:00',1);

insert into IOTransaction values(2,'01-jan-2016 08:30:00',0);
insert into IOTransaction values(2,'01-jan-2016 12:30:00',1);
insert into IOTransaction values(2,'01-jan-2016 13:30:00',0);
insert into IOTransaction values(2,'01-jan-2016 17:45:00',1);
insert into IOTransaction values(2,'02-jan-2016 08:31:00',0);
insert into IOTransaction values(2,'02-jan-2016 12:31:00',1);
insert into IOTransaction values(2,'02-jan-2016 13:31:00',0);
insert into IOTransaction values(2,'02-jan-2016 17:46:00',1);

with ins as (
    select ioPrsnRefId,
        convert(date, ioTransactionDate) as date,
        IOTransactionDate,
        row_number() over (partition by ioPrsnRefId, convert(date, ioTransactionDate) order by ioTransactionDate) rn
    from IOTransaction
    where ioStatus = 0

),
outs as (
    select ioPrsnRefId,
        convert(date, ioTransactionDate) as date,
        IOTransactionDate,
        row_number() over (partition by ioPrsnRefId, convert(date, ioTransactionDate) order by ioTransactionDate desc) rn
    from IOTransaction
    where ioStatus = 1
)
SELECT p.prsnCode [Sicil No]
    ,p.[prsnName1]
    ,p.[prsnName2]
    ,t.[ioTransactionDate]
    ,[Giris/Cikis] = (
  case 
  when [ioStatus] = 0 then 'Giris' 
  when [ioStatus] = 1 then 'Cikis' 
  else 'Uzaya Gitti' end )
FROM [IOTransaction] t
left join dbo.Person p on t.ioPrsnRefId = p.prsnRefId 
left join ins on p.prsnRefId = ins.ioPrsnRefId
    and t.ioTransactionDate = ins.ioTransactionDate
left join outs on p.prsnRefId = outs.ioPrsnRefId
    and t.ioTransactionDate = outs.ioTransactionDate
where ins.rn = 1 or outs.rn=1
```

Comment: thanks for your time... your query gives 414,691 rows in 30 seconds , mine gives 417,727 rows in 3 minutes... and with a time condition `ioTransactionDate > '2016-12-01 00:00:00.000'` mine 66901 rows against yours 63,944 rows

Comment: and some duplicate results in yours... [see picture](http://imgh.us/Untitled_812.png)

Comment: Mine will have dupes if there are duplicate checkins/outs at exactly the same time - but that seems like bad data? You could just DISTINCT to get rid of them. As to why I am returning *less* despite duplicates, not so sure? Do you have ioStatus other than 0 and 1? Maybe add "or (ins.rn is null and outs.rn is null)" to the end